# Google Maps Android API v2 more precise toScreenLocation() for lat lng

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, mercator

the projection.toScreenLocation() in API v2 returns a point containing two ints. I need more precision than that (either float, or double) as I need subsequent conversions back to latlngs from these screen coordinates to be almost exactly the same value as the original coordinates. Is there a good library or implementation of mercator projections in Java to achieve this?